Simple concat two array of objects problem
How can I remove the middle ] and [?
plan_cookie = plan_cookie.concat(JSON.stringify(protect_plan_from_db));

alert("2.1 after CONCAT plan_cookie = " + JSON.stringify(plan_cookie));

/*

2.1 after CONCAT plan_cookie = 
   "[{\"id\":1,\"productId\":1,\"planDescription\":\"No Protection Plan\",\"originalPrice\":0,\"salePrice\":0,\"active\":1},
    {\"id\":2,\"productId\":1,\"planDescription\":\"1 Year Extension Protection Plan\",\"originalPrice\":69.99,\"salePrice\":69.99,\"active\":1},
    {\"id\":3,\"productId\":1,\"planDescription\":\"2 Year Extension Protection Plan\",\"originalPrice\":89.99,\"salePrice\":89.99,\"active\":1},
    {\"id\":4,\"productId\":1,\"planDescription\":\"3 Year Extension Protection Plan\",\"originalPrice\":109.99,\"salePrice\":109.99,\"active\":1},
    {\"id\":5,\"productId\":1,\"planDescription\":\"4 Year Extension Protection Plan\",\"originalPrice\":129.99,\"salePrice\":129.99,\"active\":1}]
    [{\"id\":6,\"productId\":3,\"planDescription\":\"No Protection Plan\",\"originalPrice\":0,\"salePrice\":0,\"active\":1},
    {\"id\":7,\"productId\":3,\"planDescription\":\"1 Year Extension Protection Plan\",\"originalPrice\":79.99,\"salePrice\":79.99,\"active\":1},
    {\"id\":8,\"productId\":3,\"planDescription\":\"2 Year Extension Protection Plan\",\"originalPrice\":99.99,\"salePrice\":99.99,\"active\":1}]"

*/


What if to stringify the result of concat. Ensure that your plan_cookie and protect_plan_from_db are both arrays before concatenation, and then do JSON.stringify.
const plan_cookie = [{"id":1,"productId":1,"planDescription":"No Protection Plan","originalPrice":0,"salePrice":0,"active":1}, {"id":2,"productId":1,"planDescription":"1 Year Extension Protection Plan","originalPrice":69.99,"salePrice":69.99,"active":1}, {"id":3,"productId":1,"planDescription":"2 Year Extension Protection Plan","originalPrice":89.99,"salePrice":89.99,"active":1}, {"id":4,"productId":1,"planDescription":"3 Year Extension Protection Plan","originalPrice":109.99,"salePrice":109.99,"active":1}, {"id":5,"productId":1,"planDescription":"4 Year Extension Protection Plan","originalPrice":129.99,"salePrice":129.99,"active":1}];
const protect_plan_from_db = [{"id":6,"productId":3,"planDescription":"No Protection Plan","originalPrice":0,"salePrice":0,"active":1}, {"id":7,"productId":3,"planDescription":"1 Year Extension Protection Plan","originalPrice":79.99,"salePrice":79.99,"active":1}, {"id":8,"productId":3,"planDescription":"2 Year Extension Protection Plan","originalPrice":99.99,"salePrice":99.99,"active":1}];

const result = plan_cookie.concat(protect_plan_from_db);
alert("2.1 after CONCAT plan_cookie = " + JSON.stringify(result));


The solution is the line below:
const combinePlans = [...JSON.parse(plan_cookie), ...protect_plan_from_db];

Thank you very much for all of your information which lead me to find the solution.
Cookie

When you posted your poorly-formatted question, another kind user edited it to make it more readable. However, we do hope that you'll learn from these edits and, when you post in the future, not repeat these mistakes.  Unfortunately, when you posted this answer, you still didn't format it. Please (a) take the time to read How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML? and refer to the Markdown help (b) [Edit] your answer to fix the formatting and remove the signature line (c) take the time to properly format your future posts. Thanks!
